# Question about change-of-basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I read a chapter in my algebra book, about change-of-basis matrix.

> Let $V$ a vectorial space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $B=\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}, B'=\{e_1',e_2',...,e_n'\}$ two basis of this vectorial space. Then, every element of basis $B'$ can be written as linear combination of vectors from $B$.
>
> $e_1' = u_{11}e_1+u_{21}e_2+\dots+u_{n1}e_n$ 
> $e_2' = u_{12}e_1+u_{22}e_2+\dots+u_{n2}e_n$ 
> $\dots \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots$ 
> $e_n' = u_{1n}e_1+u_{2n}e_2+\dots+u_{nn}e_n$ 
> Thus, $U=\begin{pmatrix}
> u_{11} && u_{12} && \dots && u_{1n} \\
> u_{21} && u_{22} && \dots && u_{2n} \\
> \vdots && \vdots && \ddots  && \vdots \\
> u_{n1} && u_{n2} && \dots && u_{nn}
> \end{pmatrix}$ is the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$.

My question is:
Why this matrix is named " from $B$ to $B'$ " if we have relation: $[v]_{B} = U * [v]_{B'}$? Shouldn't it be called "from $B'$ to $B$?
Sorry for eventually typos. I've translated this fragment from another language to english.

Comment: Your relation is based on coordinates, not basis elements. This can be confusing at first. From the $B'$ frame, all of the vectors look like they've undergone the inverse transformation. Therefore, given a set of coordinates in the old basis, we must perform the inverse transformation to see what the coordinates for the same vector look like in the new basis.

Comment: What the author wanted to say by "from B to B'" is that the matrix U makes "the passing" from coordinates in terms of base B to coordinates in base B'. But that isn't absurd? The matrix U makes the transformation from coordinates in terms of base B' in coordinates from base B. Am I wrong, or the author is wrong?

Comment: No. The basis elements of $B$ get mapped to the basis elements of $B'$. That's why it is called a change of basis matrix. The coordinates are the projections along the basis elements. We view vectors as objects independent of their representation.  Consider a change of basis that rotates $\hat e_1$ and $\hat e_2$ by $45^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise. A vector $v$ in the space doesn't move. The rotated basis vectors then view $v$ as having been rotated clockwise and so their coordinates seem to be rotated clockwise.

Comment: I agree with you. I would call this the change of basis matrix from $B'$ to $B$, all because of the relation $[v]_{B} = U[v]_{B'}$.

Comment: @Mason This is not open to opinion. In change of basis transformations, the basis elements transform covariantly and the coordinates transform contravariantly. The expression you wrote is a transformation of coordinates with respect to two sets of basis elements.

Comment: @JohnDouma Wikipedia agrees with you, and I realize that I always use this convention when dealing with coordinate changes in calculus..

Comment: @Mason I found it to be very confusing when I was learning it.

Comment: @JohnDouma It seems that the debate is between writing the coordinate transformation from $x$ to $x'$ as $x = Ux'$ vs $x' = Vx$. I go with the first option, but many differential geometry books define charts as mapping the Manifold into Euclidean space, which is seems more like the second convention.

Comment: I always forget the terminology,  but I can remember what I'm doing by looking just at the columns of the matrix.   The matrix takes vectors written in that basis and writes them in the standard basis.   With that in mind you can use the standard basis as a point of reference,  and always get, by multiplying,  to and from $B$ and $B'$.  You just need to compute an inverse and multiply now and then.

Answer (score 2):

The author is correct.... In order to see this let's apply the change of basis matrix $U$ to an arbitrary basis element in $B$;

$$U\circ\ e_1 
   =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
    u_{11} & u_{12} & \cdots & u_{1n}\\
    u_{21} & u_{22} & \cdots & u_{2n}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    u_{n1} & u_{n2} & \cdots & u_{nn}\\
  \end{array} } \right] \circ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
u_{11} \\
u_{21} \\
\vdots \\
u_{n1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$=\space u_{11}\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+u_{21}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+\dots u_{n1}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}=u_{11}e_1+u_{21}e_2+ \dots u_{n1}e_n= e'_1$$

$$ \therefore U\circ\ e_{1} = e'_{1}$$

So the matrix $U$ does, indeed, transform basis vectors from $B$ to $B'$ as the author stated.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

Per your example, let's determine the change of basis matrix U from the basis $B_1$ to the basis $B_2$.

$$e'_1=U_{B_1 \rightarrow B_2}\circ e_1=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    u_{11} & u_{12}\\
    u_{21} & u_{22}
  \end{array} } \right]\circ\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
{2u_{11}+3u_{12}}\\
{2u_{21}+3u_{22}} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
4\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$e'_2=U_{B_1 \rightarrow B_2}\circ e_2=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    u_{11} & u_{12}\\
    u_{21} & u_{22}
  \end{array} } \right]\circ\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
5 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
{8u_{11}+5u_{12}} \\
{8u_{21}+5u_{22}} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So we now have 2 sets of 2 equations with 2 unknowns each which are completely determined. This system gives us the following which you are free to check...

$$U_{B_1 \rightarrow B_2}= {1\over7}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    {2} & {1}\\
    {1\over2} & {9}
  \end{array} } \right]$$

$\textbf{EDIT 2:}$

Let's consider a scenario where I am using a certain 2D-basis $B$, while my friend is using a basis which, from my perspective, looks like $B'=\{\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
5 \\
\end{bmatrix} \}$

Let's say my friend refers to the vector $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ in his coordinate system.
In order for me to understand what vector my friend is referring to in my coordinate system I have to compose it with the matrix whose columns are his basis vectors.

$$U\circ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    2 & 8\\
    3 & 5
  \end{array} } \right]\circ \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = 1\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}+0\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the vector which my friend "sees" as $\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ looks like $\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ in my basis $B$ which is clearly...

$$e'_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
u_{11} \\
u_{21} \\
\end{bmatrix} = u_{11}e_1+u_{21}e_2$$

As required...

Comment: But for a different basis than e? This works? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: For example, if I have basis $B_1=\{(2,3),(8,5)\}$ and $ B_2=\{(1,4),(3,7)\}$ then how I transform vectors from $B_1$ to vectors in $B_2$ by multiplying matrix U with them?

Comment: Of course,   is an arbitrary basis vector.  The information about your specific basis  will be encoded in the change of basis matrix .

Comment: I tried your metod but i can't get it. Can you please solve my example with your method from above and put as an answer? Thanks you very much

Comment: But it's not the same matrix. Because coordinates of $(1,4)$ in base $B_1$ are $(27/14,-5/14) \linebreak 2/7*({{2},{3}})+1/14*({{8},{5}})=({{1},{4})}$ is false

Comment: You are misunderstanding something very essential about linear algebra. N-tuples are not vectors. They are representations of vectors with respect to a certain basis. The vector (1,4) doesn't "look like" (1,4) from the perspective of $_2$. Anyone using the basis $_2$ will "see" the vector represented by (1,4) in the standard basis as the 2-tuple (1,0). This seems to be where your misunderstanding is stemming from.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answer but I still don't  understand. In my question I said that the matrix $U$ should have on every collumn the coordinates of vectors from basis $B'$ in basis $B$. The matrix that result from your edit dont have on first collumn coordinates of $(1,4)$ in basis $B$.

Comment: @MathLearner I hope the second edit makes things more clear.

Comment: $n$ tuples *are* vectors, in $\mathbb R^n.$ In fact,  $U$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb R^n:$ it maps the coordinates of vectors $v$ in the basis $B'$ to those in the basis $B$. This is where perhaps the confusion arises. One has $U$ doing double-duty. Depending on one's perspective.

Comment: True, but depending on your coordinate system the components of the n-tuple describing a specific vector will change while the vector itself will not. This is what I was trying to convey... That our description of a thing is not the thing itself.

Answer (score 1):

One can view this process in two different ways:

$1).\ $ using the definition of a change of basis matrix, one has that $U,$ viewed as a linear isomorphism of $V$, satisfies  $Ue_i=e'_i.$  That is all the author is saying here.

The confusion arises because

$2).\ U,$ the matrix, also transforms the *coordinates* of a *fixed* vector $v$ in the basis $B'$ to the *coordinates* of *that same vector* in the basis $B.$ To see why, refer to your own calculation:

$e_1' = u_{11}e_1+u_{21}e_2+\dots+u_{n1}e_n$ 
$e_2' = u_{12}e_1+u_{22}e_2+\dots+u_{n2}e_n$ 
$\dots \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots$ 
$e_n' = u_{1n}e_1+u_{2n}e_2+\dots+u_{nn}e_n$

and take a fixed vector $v$ and express it as

$\tag1 v=a_1e_1'+\cdots + a_n e_n'.$

The coordinates of $v$ in the basis B' are $[a_1,\cdots, a_n].$ Now, substitute for the $e_i'$ into $(1)$ and you will obtain the coordinates of $v$ in the $B$ basis. To finish, observe how $U$ encodes the change of coordinates. Note that the vector $v$ is *fixed*. It's its coordinate expression that changes, as the basis changes.